# ICS: How can I disable home button?

Tags: android, button

I want to disable home button, below code can work before ICS, who have solution to do it on ICS?

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the FLAG_FULLSCREEN.

Documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I try to do it, the activity is full screen, but can't disable home button.

Comment: Hmmm. Completely disable the home button? Didn't know that was possible at all! Sorry, can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on the unlocker of ICS, today i found that LockBot can disable the home key, but i can't find the reason yet. App link: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jackdoit.lockbotfree.